# Redis: кэшировать объект или его json?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

Всем привет. Давно использую Redis, но только сейчас задался этим вопросом.

Есть, к примеру, следующий код:

```
$article = Cache::rememberForever('articles', function(){
  return Article::all();
});
```

Где в итоге в переменной article содержится объект, полученный через Eloquent. В то же время, в ОЗУ это занимает гораздо больше памяти, нежели такое:

```
$article = Cache::rememberForever('articles', function(){
  return Article::all()->toJson();
});
```

С другой стороны, тем самым мы лишаем себя всех возможностей Eloquent модели и коллекций в целом. Но мы можем сделать следующее:

```
$article = Cache::rememberForever('articles', function(){
  return Article::all()->toJson();
});
$article = json_decode($article);
$article = Article::hydrate($article);
```

Но это займет больше ресурсов со стороны сервера. Как найти золотую середину в данном случае?

> Весь вопрос пишу "на коленке", он имеет более абстрактную часть, где
>   важна идеология, а не синтаксис, поэтому за синтаксические ошибки
>   прошу не винить. Пример идет на Laravel.

Comment: Вам жалко оперативной памяти? При гидрации будет происходить много лишних действий, в том числе и возможны обращения к БД. Какой тогда смысл в кеше?

Comment: @korytoff нет, тут дело не в этом. Я именно про то, что лучше сделать: гидрацию (что-либо другое для получения модели) или же хранить в оперативной памяти весь объект.

Comment: У вас цель то какая? Скорость или оптимизация оперативной программы для работы с малым объемом оперативки? Все от целей зависит